# Set dropdown list to initial value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have manually added values in dropdown list using for loop.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        date0.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        date1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        date2.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        date3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    {
        month0.Items.Add(j.ToString());
        month1.Items.Add(j.ToString());
        month2.Items.Add(j.ToString());
        month3.Items.Add(j.ToString());

    }

    for (int k = DateTime.Now.Year; k <= 2020; k++)
    {
        yyyy0.Items.Add(k.ToString());
        yyyy1.Items.Add(k.ToString());
        yyyy2.Items.Add(k.ToString());
        yyyy3.Items.Add(k.ToString());
    }
```

Now on clear button I want to clear out these values and set them to initial. I tried calling the function in which I have initialized them. But it's not happening. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: what do you mean by initial? the first record on the list?

Comment: what is happening instead?

Comment: @DaveA: It still shows the changed (selected) values

Comment: It should set itself to 1/1/2013. Which are my initial values

Comment: How are you doing this, maybe you are adding it all over again, can you post the relevant code and error if any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset it to the first record by setting the SelectedIndex to 0 so that the first element in the list will be selected:

```
date0.SelectedIndex = 0;
date1.SelectedIndex = 0;
date2.SelectedIndex = 0;
date3.SelectedIndex = 0;


month0.SelectedIndex = 0;
month1.SelectedIndex = 0;
month2.SelectedIndex = 0;
month3.SelectedIndex = 0;

yyyy0.SelectedIndex = 0;
yyyy1.SelectedIndex = 0;
yyyy2.SelectedIndex = 0;
yyyy3.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

You can put this on the Clear button.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to fill the dropdownlist only if the page is Not postback

```
if (! IsPostBack) {

   //Fill out the dropdown list

}
```

and make sure to set SelectedIndex = 0 for those you want to set back to initial values

```
month0.SelectedIndex = 0;
```